# jquery autocomplete cities with geonames - avoid duplicates in autocomplete suggestion

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, geonames

I'm using the jqueryUI autocomplete functionality (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) to search surrounding shops of cities in germany and austria. my code is the following:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?lang=de&country=DE&country=AT&isNameRequired=true&featureClass=A&featureCode=ADM3&featureCode=ADM4&featureCode=ADM1",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                }...
```

the problem now is, for austria, i need all the administrative devisions ADM3, ADM1... to get all of the cities. For Germany ADM4 would be enough. But because of the other codes, I get Berlin for example three times, because its ADM3, ADM1 and ADM4.

How can i remove the duplicates of certain cities to autosuggest it only once?